# Closed expression of a specific splitting of a continued fraction

Tags: number-theory, rational-numbers, continued-fractions, golden-ratio

Recently in my research I stumbled upon this splitting of a periodic continued fraction. I wondered whether there is any closed expression or literature on this topic.

## Visualizing continued fractions by rectangles

It is known that a continued fraction $a = [n_0, n_1, ...]$ can be visualized by filling in squares of a rectangular sheet of paper (as described [here](https://r-knott.surrey.ac.uk/Fibonacci/cfINTRO.html)). I illustrate the procedure on the periodic continued fraction $a = [\overline{3, 1, 2, 1}]$:

Take a rectangle with width $a$ and height $1$. Then we can fill in $3$ squares from the left, then $1$ square from the bottom, then $2$ squares from the left, then $1$ square from the bottom, then the procedure repeats.

[Illustrating Rectangle filled by squares](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Keg49.png)

## Adapting the visualization to generate a real number

Instead of always filling the squares in from the left, I do the following:

- If $3$ squares are removed, then remove $2$ from the left and $1$ from the right.
- If $2$ squares are removed, then remove $1$ from the left and $1$ from the right.

When doing this, the yet "empty" space of the paper is no longer on the right but in the middle of the rectangle and converges to a specific x-coordinate.

[Illustrating Left-Right-Fillings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2jKG.png)

Generalizing, this operation takes in a purely periodic continued fraction (here $a = [\overline{3, 1, 2, 1}]$) and a sequence of rational numbers (here $(\frac{2}{3}, \frac{1}{2})$) to split $a$ into two parts.
Is there any closed expression for the resulting x-coordinate? Is there literature on that kind of operation?